Express middleware for DTO validation throws undefined TypeError on valid payload
I have a POST /login route in my Express application where I'm using a payload validation middleware before the controller, structured as follows:
profileRouter.post(
  "/login",
  logRequestBody,
  validatePayloadAsDto(LoginRequestDto),
  profileController.login,
);

Despite confirming that req.body contains the required fields, the validation middleware throws a TypeError during execution, indicating that the email field is undefined.
The validatePayloadAsDto middleware uses class-validator's validate() method and class-transformer's plainToInstance() method. The plainToInstance() transformation appears to fail, as the stack trace points to this function when the error occurs.
I have attempted the following debugging steps:

Logging req.body: I added a logRequestBody middleware to verify the payload being passed to the route. The log confirmed that req.body contains all required fields, including email.
Logging within validatePayloadAsDto(): I added a log statement inside the validation middleware to confirm that req.body is being received correctly. The log again showed the expected data.
Narrowed to plainToInstance(): Based on the stack trace and process of elimination, the issue seems to occur during the transformation by plainToInstance(). More so, removing the validation middleware resolves the error.
Modifying instantiation: I tried moving the instantiation call out of the validate() method, assigning the result to a variable, and passing it instead. The same error occurred.

Here is the relevant code for the validation middleware:
export function validatePayloadAsDto<T extends BaseDto>(dto: {
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  new (...args: any[]): T;
}): RequestHandler {
  return async (req: Request, _res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    try {
      console.log(
        `Request Body from validator: ${JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 2)}`,
      );
      const errors: ValidationError[] = await validate(
        plainToInstance(dto, req.body),
        {
          whitelist: true,
          forbidNonWhitelisted: true,
          validationError: { target: false },
        },
      );
      if (errors.length > 0) {
        return next(new DtoValidationError("Invalid data", errors));
      }

      return next();
    } catch (error: unknown) {
      return next(
        new UnexpectedError("Unexpected validation error", error as Error),
      );
    }
  };
}


The POST /register route uses this same validation middleware, albeit with a different DTO class, and behaves as expected.
How can I resolve this issue and ensure the middleware validates the payload as expected?
